# JpaRepository implementation- Lists vs. Sets

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm building my first Spring Boot app using JPA and have setup my data repositories and services like this:

```
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {
    Set<Foo> findAllByActiveInstallationIsNull();
}
```

Then a CrudService

```
public interface CrudService<T extends BaseEntity> {
    Set<T> findAll();

    T findById(Long id);

    T save(T object);

    void delete(T object);

    void deleteById(Long id);
}
```

along with an example class service interface that extends it

```
public interface FooService extends CrudService<Foo> {
    Set<Foo> findAllAvailable();
    Foo getIfAvailable(Long id);
}
```

an abstract class for service implementations

```
public abstract class AbstractJpaService<T extends BaseEntity, R extends JpaRepository<T, Long>> implements CrudService<T> {
    protected R repository;

    public AbstractJpaService(R repository) {
        this.repository = repository; }

    @Override
    public Set<T> findAll() {
        return new HashSet<>(repository.findAll()); }

    @Override
    public T findById(Long id) {
        return repository.findById(id).orElse(null); }

    @Override
    public T save(T object) {
        return repository.save(object); }

    @Override
    public void delete(T object) {
        repository.delete(object); }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(Long id) {
        repository.deleteById(id); }
}
```

and finally an example of an actual service class that extends the above-mentioned one:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class FooJpaService extends AbstractJpaService<Foo, FooRepository> implements FooService {
    public FooJpaService(FooRepository repository) {
        super(repository);
    }
 ///
}
```

I wrote some service layer logic, controllers and once I was happy with the first iteration I've done some postman testing that worked without a hitch.

Then I took a step back and started writing some unit tests for my service classes only to realize that while findAll() in my services returns Set as I intended, the JpaRepository methods and by extension my own repos give List.

```
    @Test
    void findAll() {
        Set<Foo> returnFooSet = new HashSet<>();
        returnFooSet.add(new Foo(boo, 1d, 2d));
        returnFooSet.add(new Foo(baz, 3d, 4d));
        when(fooRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(returnFooSet);
        Set<Foo> foos = service.findAll();

        assertNotNull(foos);
        assertEquals(2, foos.size());
    }
```

resulting in thenReturn() method expecting a List.

Sorry for the wall of code, but I'm pretty new at this and very much confused so figured I'll provide excessive context even if most could have been assumed, since my newbie implementations may be weird and faulty.

So what gives?
I've read about the benefits of using Sets in JPA and most of the code examples I've seen use them.
My own findAllByArgument methods with Set returns like the ones you see in the repository have been working just fine, so I assume nothing stops me from overriding basic FindAll() methods in all of my repos (since CrudRepository seems to have just Iterable there), but that seems... off?

Should I be using Sets with JPA? What are good practices in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only rule of thumb regarding `List` or `Set` in `JPA` world (with Hibernate under the hood) is to always use `Set` on a `@ManyToMany` relationship and never `List`.
Other than that I am not aware of anything else. Still, I can guess that maybe `Set` is better in terms of performance since it is unordered while `List` is ordered. Given that `JpaRepository` has a method that returns `List` this eventually better performance might not be relevant enough.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but how one would go about making JpaRepository methods to return Sets?

Comment: Assuming `Set<Foo> findAllByActiveInstallationIsNull();` works that is the only way. You need to add the methods on your own.

Comment: JPA will convert the `List` to a `Set` which could cause query and perhaps some performance and memory usage issues.